# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Tags: python, pypdf

I have two versions of Python in my computer, 3.6.4 and 3.7. I can import module PyPDF2 in the former but not in the latter, Python 3.7. When I try, I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

How can I import PyPDF2 in Python 3.7? I have the same problem with other modules as well.

Answer (score 1):

For each python version, import `sys` and `print(sys.path)`.

This will show you where your available import sources are, namely the `site-packages` directory.

**If you think the packages are compatible between your two versions:**

Copy the contents of the `site-packages` directory from the working version into the `site-packages` directory for the non working version.

**If not:**

Install the package(s) correctly into the right location, ideally using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).